# Unable to start neo4j server in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, neo4j

Recently I installed  Neo4j (community edition) 3.0.0-M04.It worked fine for once when I started it again after restarting my computer it shows the following error.

`Starting Neo4j.
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.function.Functions.nullFunction()Ljava/util/function/Function;
    at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Settings.setting(Settings.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Settings.setting(Settings.java:101)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings.<clinit>(GraphDatabaseSettings.java:157)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.BaseServerConfigLoader.overrideEmbeddedDefaults(BaseServerConfigLoader.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.BaseServerConfigLoader.loadConfig(BaseServerConfigLoader.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.createConfig(Bootstrapper.java:199)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.start(CommunityBootstrapper.java:48)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.main(CommunityBootstrapper.java:35)`

Answer (score 1):

perhaps try

`sudo service neo4j start`

this worked for me in a similar context https://github.com/in3rsha/bitcoin-to-neo4j/issues/1